# How can I correctly format my SQL trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

For some background this is part of an assignment for my Databases class. We have a set of tables that all entail towards Company information. This includes WORKS_ON which shows the hours that Employees work on specific projects. The goal of my code was to write a trigger that prevents a user from assigning more than 40 hours of total work to one employee. I intended to do this via obtaining the sum of hours that are currently in the table associated with the new row's Employee SSN(Essn). From there I meant to add the sum to the new row's hours and compare to 40. If the amount was more than 40, then a custom message is concatenated and an error is raised to the user. The professor included PHP which handles the printing of that error for me. As of now the only potential fix/error I can think of is that it is not legal to perform arithmetic within the if statement. Please let me know if you see anything I need to fix/improve.

```
DELIMITER &&
CREATE TRIGGER MAXTOTALHOURS
BEFORE INSERT ON WORKS_ON FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE sumHours integer;
DECLARE customMessage VARCHAR(100);
SELECT SUM(hours) INTO sumHours FROM WORKS_ON WHERE Essn = New.Essn;
IF (sumHours + New.hours > 40) THEN
SET customMessage = concat('You entered', New.hours, '. You currently work ', sumHours, '. You are over 40 hours!');
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = customMessage;
END IF;
END &&
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: If there's an error message and mysql version it would be useful to show that too.

Comment: Trigger approach is not what will prevent this operations in concurrent environment. If two sessions will insert two rows with 39 hours it will not reject them due to transaction isolation. You need an extra summary table with check constraint, in which you need to insert summed up hours calculated in trigger.

Comment: I am asking what I need to change, my trigger currently prevents rows being added to the WORKS_ON table. There isn't an error message since the code successfully integrates as a trigger

Comment: *As of now the only potential fix/error I can think of is that it is not legal to perform arithmetic within the if statement.* No, this is legal.

Comment: The trouble is that you are referring to the SAME TABLE that triggers the action which is not allowed because it would be recursive. From the docs: `Cannot make changes to a table that is already in use (reading or writing) by the statement invoking the stored function.` You could update some other table, but generally, storing a calculated sum is a bad idea, since a query could retrieve the calculation.